Error running phpstorm on windows 7 32 bit OS
I have installed phpstorm on my windows7 32 bit laptop, clicked on finish. However when I want to open the phpstorm, it won't open.
Php version is 21.14
Deleting and reinstalling the phpstorm version 2021 did not help.  I also noticed that the app was not on task manager after clicking on it. I am wondering if it is because I am using an old version of php storm or its because I use windows 7

AFAIK that version does not support x86 (32bit). I think 2020.1 or so was the latest that worked on 32 bit Windows.
